# Excel for Mac - chart with no interpolation of discontinuities?

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to draw a chart in Excel for Mac with no interpolation on discontinuities, like this:

[image: sketch illustrating what i want]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pnuts' approach, but tweak the data, so the horizontal segments are one series in the chart, and the vertical segments (if needed) are another.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you require (and have created the example with Excel 2007) but I think you should be able to achieve what you require if you plot enough separate data series and format each to suit (using Scatter with Straight Lines):

[image: SU579408 example]